# XSLT - How to wrap adjacent elements with specific attributes

Tags: xslt

I'm new to xsl.  I found something similar but can't quite tweak it to my use.

Input:

```
<section>
  <heading>some heading text</heading>
  <amendment chapter="1">
    <foo/>
  </amendment>
  <amendment chapter="2">
    <bar/>
  </amendment>
  <amendment chapter="3">
    <baz/>
  </amendment>
  <heading>some heading text</heading>
  <amendment chapter="1">
    <baz/>
  </amendment>
</section>
```

To wrap elements with attribute "chapter='1' or chapter='2'".
Output:

```
<section>
  <heading>some heading text</heading>
  <newwrapper>
    <amendment chapter="1">
      <foo/>
    </amendment>
    <amendment chapter="2">
      <bar/>
    </amendment>
  </newwrapper>
  <amendment chapter="3">
    <baz/>
  </amendment>
  <heading>some heading text</heading>
  <newwrapper>
    <amendment chapter="1">
      <baz/>
    </amendment>
  </newwrapper>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

**I. This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <section>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="*" 
                        group-adjacent="self::amendment and @chapter =(1,2)">
     <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()">
         <newwrapper>
           <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
         </newwrapper>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
         <xsl:sequence select="current-group()"/>
       </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
  </section>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<section>
    <heading>some heading text</heading>
    <amendment chapter="1">
        <foo/>
    </amendment>
    <amendment chapter="2">
        <bar/>
    </amendment>
    <amendment chapter="3">
        <baz/>
    </amendment>
    <heading>some heading text</heading>
    <amendment chapter="1">
        <baz/>
    </amendment>
</section>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<section>
   <heading>some heading text</heading>
   <newwrapper>
      <amendment chapter="1">
               <foo/>
         </amendment>
      <amendment chapter="2">
               <bar/>
         </amendment>
   </newwrapper>
   <amendment chapter="3">
            <baz/>
      </amendment>
   <heading>some heading text</heading>
   <newwrapper>
      <amendment chapter="1">
               <baz/>
         </amendment>
   </newwrapper>
</section>
```

**Explanation**:

Proper use of **[`xsl:for-each-group`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#xsl-for-each-group)** with the `group-adjacent` attribute.

---

**II. XSLT 1.0 Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="amendment[not(@chapter >2)]" use=
 "generate-id(preceding-sibling::*
                [not(self::amendment and @chapter &lt;= 2)][1])"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>


 <xsl:template match=
 "*[not(self::amendment and @chapter &lt;= 2)
  and
    following-sibling::*[1][self::amendment and not(@chapter >2)]
    ]">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <newwrapper>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup"
                        select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
  </newwrapper>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="*" mode="inGroup">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="amendment[not(@chapter >2)]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the same XML document (above), the same, dorrect result is produced**.

**Explanation**:

Proper use of:

1. Utilizing and overriding of the **[identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html)**.
2. **[Keys](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#key)** to define a group of adjacent `amendment` elements with `chapter` attribute not greater than `2`, as a function of the **[`generate-id()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#function-generate-id)** of the immediate preceding-sibling element for that group.

Comment: I can't use XSLT 2.0 Solution.  And XSLT 1.0 Solution does not work for some reason.  The output I get is:
<section>
    <heading>some heading text</heading>
    <newwrapper xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt">
        <amendment chapter="2">
            <bar/>
        </amendment>
    </newwrapper>
    <amendment chapter="3">
        <baz/>
    </amendment>
    <heading>some heading text</heading>
    <newwrapper xmlns:xalan="http://xml.apache.org/xslt"/>
</section>

And the attribute chapter needs to be a String, not a number.

Comment: @dcdc: Sorry, this is a nasty SO code formatting bug -- it often replaces the XPath `[1]` with `[2]`, thinking that this is an HTML anchor. I corrected the `[2]` back to [1]` now and the transformation produces (again :) ) the wanted result. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Dimitre Novatchev, I modified the attribute to a string and the xslt works.  Thanks.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:key name="kFollowing" match="amendment[(@chapter='1' or @chapter='2')]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::*[not(self::amendment and (@chapter='1' or @chapter='2'))][1])"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::amendment and (@chapter='1' or @chapter='2')) and following-sibling::*[1][self::amendment and (@chapter='1' or @chapter='2')]]">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <newwrapper>
            <xsl:apply-templates mode="inGroup" select="key('kFollowing', generate-id())"/>
        </newwrapper>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="inGroup">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="amendment[(@chapter='1' or @chapter='2')]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```